# VS2013 - Team Foundation Error - no matching loose object

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I installed VS2013 and - by default - it checks for existing repository/git settings. It shows me my branches, my repos and all those stuff.
I'm also able to commit my changes. But, when e.g. right-clicking a file and selecting `View History...` the following popup is shown:

[image: VisualStudioError]

telling

> Object not found - no matching loose object

I've already tried

```
--git gc
--git fsck
```

and some other proposals found here/in the internet. Nothing helped so far. Unfortunately `SourceTree` or `Tortoise-git` do not complain and I can `git` around the whole day.

So, I am not sure if this is an issue with git, VS2013 or Team Foundation Server or whatever is done under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You could new a local repository, do some changes. Commit, view the history. See if it is effective.

If it works on local repository.Then try to delete the problem repository in local dev machine (Get a backup).ReClone the repository. Commit and sync, try it agian.